# Magento 2: Change quote from current quote to other quote id

Tags: addtocart, quote, magento2.2

Please let me know how can I change my current quote to any other quote saved in database using an event observer in `magento 2.2`

Comment: You mean you want to copy your old quote object into new quote object ?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 5):

Give a try

```
   $quote = $this->quoteRepository->get(**<Your_quote_id>**);
   $quote->setIsActive(1);
   $quoteRepository->save($quote);
   $this->checkoutSession->replaceQuote($quote);
```

where variables

> ```
> $this->quoteRepository instance of Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface
>
> $this->checkoutSession instance of Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The following controller resets the quote Magento2, setting of 'other quote id' should be similar - just replace the 'null' to appropriate quoteId:

```
class Start extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /** @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session */
    private $session;

    /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository */
    private $quoteRepository;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $session
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $session,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);

        $this->session = $session;
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Controller execute action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {

        $quote = $this->session->getQuote();
        $this->session->setQuoteId(null);
        $quote->setIsActive(false);
        $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);

        return $this->_redirect($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
    }
}
```