# Magento 2 add to cart programmatically not working

Tags: magento2, addtocart, quote

Here am have a custom api at that API call am trying to add a product to cart but am not getting it.

```
namespace Vendor\Cart\Model;
  use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey;
  use Vendor\Cart\Api\HelloInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;  
  use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
  use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
  use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository;
  use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;

class Hello implements HelloInterface
{

        protected $cart;
        protected $formKey;
        protected $request;
        protected $_wishlistRepository;
        protected $_productRepository;
        protected $_sellerCollection;
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
    FormKey $formKey,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    {
     $this->cart = $cart;
     $this->formKey = $formKey;
     $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
     $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
     $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }
     public function new(){
     $QuoteId=636;
     $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($QuoteId);
     $d = $quote->getData();
     $quoteId = $d['entity_id'];
     //***********************************     */

     $quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($QuoteId);
     $items = $quote->getAllItems();

     $params = array(
          'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
          'product' => 37,
          // 'sku' => 'SKU590003557',
          'quote_id' => $quoteId,
          'qty' => 1
      );
     $product = $this->productRepository->getById(37);
     /****************************************** */

     $this->cart->addProduct($product,$params);
     $this->cart->save();
   }
}
```

Where am doing wrong?. can i get help? Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you please share any logs or error you got? because its working from my end.

Comment: Does the quote id 636 is assigned with frontend have you checked ? if not, display current quote id in cart page to verify.

Comment: `"message": "Class TW\\Product\\Helper\\Data does not exist",`,`C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\hylosh\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\ObjectManager\\Definition\\Runtime.php(44): Magento\\Framework\\Code\\Reader\\ClassReader->getConstructor('Vendor\\\\...')\n#1 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\hylosh\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer.php(48):`

Comment: @Ranganathan Quote id assigned by API call through postman

Comment: @PraveenNegimani then you need to assign this quote to frontend(checkoutsession) to check your cart - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196548/magento-2-change-quote-from-current-quote-to-other-quote-id#196681

Comment: I need to add product this (static) cart

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you. I used the following code to add the product to current quote programmatically.

```
        $storeId = $this->_storemanager->getStore()->getId();        
        $product_coll = $this->productRepository->getById($productId, false, $storeId);
        $params = array(
            'form_key' => $this->_formkey->getFormKey(),
            'product' => $productId, //product Id
            'qty'   => $qty //quantity of product                
            );  
        $this->_cart->addProduct($product_coll, $params);
        $this->_cart->save();
```

Let me know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace this code in your controller,
FYI, No need to use cart Model in __construct().

```
/**
 * @var PageFactory
 */
protected $resultPageFactory;
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey
 */
protected $formKey;
/**
 * @param Context $context
 * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->formKey = $formKey;
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
}

/**
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
 */
public function execute()
{
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $params = array(
            'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
            'product' =>12,//product Id
            'qty'   =>1,//quantity of product
            'price' =>100 //product price
        );
        $this->_redirect("checkout/cart/add/form_key/", $params);
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
    return $resultPage;
}
```

Comment: how to add multiple items?

Answer (score 0):

If you want minicart to be updated when you add product to cart by controller you need to add your controller to file section.xml like in Magento_Checkout module:

```
Magento/Checkout/etc/frontend/sections.xml
```

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3287#issuecomment-179773861